# How to Access WCF service in Blazor Server App

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, blazor-server-side

I am learning about Blazor server apps. We have an existing asp.net MVC application that communicates with a WCF service via netTcpBindings. We are now thinking about moving our development into .net Core so based on that Blazor Server seems very cool to start with.

My question is, how can I consume the existing WCF netTcpBindings service on any new Blazor Server application? I have tried googling this but could not find much on the subject. Is it even possible to consume a WCF service in .Net core (because from what it seems WCF is not brought into .Net core)?

Comment: .Net core still supports WCF netTcpBindings service. .Net core provides dotnet-svcutil tool to generate proxy classes to call WCF services. For more information about dotnet-svcutil, you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x

Answer (score 3):

It is still possible to consume WCF from a .Net Core application. Bear in mind that it is nothing else than a communication protocol, so it doesn't really matter what "language" you are using as long as you are able to connect to the server providing the service and you implement the protocol.

Luckily the Microsoft people have that in .Net Core so

Say you have the following service:

[image: IUserAuthenticationService]

on your Server on the Startup.cs file you can then do something like this:

[image]

Done, you may now invoke your WCF service from your .Net Core server